# Sort an array depending on given set of characters within each element

Tags: ruby

I have an array made of a number of elements read from a .txt file. Each element is long and has a lot of information, for instance:
`20201102066000000000000000000000000020052IC04008409Z8000000000030546676591AFIP`

All the lines are already part of the array `lines_array`, but I need to sort them out depending on the content of the 36° character until the 51°, which in the example provided above would be:
`20052IC04008409Z`

I was already able to catch the patterns from each of the elements in the array:

```
    lines_array = File.readlines(complete_filename)

    pattern = nil
    lines_array.each do |line|
    pattern = line[36] + line[37] + line[38] + line[39] + line[40] + line[41] + line[42] + line[43] + 
    line[44] + line[45] + line[46] + line[47] + line[48] + line[49] + line[50] + line[51]
    end
```

What I need to do now is to be able to sort **alphabetically** all the elements of the array (with the long elements) based on the content of the variable variable `pattern`. I tried with methods `sort` and `sort_by` but I wasn't able to pass my variable `pattern` as a parameter. For example, a correct order of three given elements would be:

`20201102066000000000000000000000000020001IC04180127X8000000000030546676591AFIP`
`20201104066000000000000000000000000020001IC04182757T8000000000030546676591AFIP`
`20201102066000000000000000000000000020001IC05020641D8000000000030546676591AFIP`

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, there are easier and cleaner ways to extract the substring you're after, you could use [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) or [`String#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-slice):

```
# These do the same thing, use whichever reads better to you.
pattern = line[36, 16]
pattern = line.slice(36, 16)
pattern = line[36..51]
pattern = line.slice(36..51)
```

Then you can [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) on that slice by using a block with `sort_by`:

```
sorted = lines_array.sort_by { |str| str[36, 16] }
```

Comment: Range version might make more sense to the OP since that is how they described the positioning. e.g. `str[36..51]`

Comment: @engineersmnky True, I just habitually use the `start, length` form.

Comment: One could instead use `.sort_by { |str| str[36..-1] }`, the only difference being the possible ordering of ties (strings `s` for which `s[36..51]` is the same). For example, `a = ["5123G4", "810632RR", "2902", "60135278ZZ", "71063"]; b = a.sort_by { |s| s[1..3] } #=> ["60135278ZZ", "810632RR", "71063", "5123G4", "2902"]; c = a.sort_by { |s| s[1..-1] } #=> ["60135278ZZ", "71063", "810632RR", "5123G4", "2902"]`. Note that `b[1] == c[2]` and `b[2] == c[1]`. That's because `b[1..3] == c[1..3]`,